# What should be done about users who only post (low-quality) questions?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

As I explore the site more, I've noticed that there are certain users that only post questions, and never post any answers. Even worse, some post questions and never accept any answers given to them! I'm not here to complain about how these users are taking without giving, but rather to ask what can be one to encourage these users to contribute back to the community.

While the community seems to be happy to help anyone who makes a reasonable attempt at a question, it is my understanding that communities by-and-large become ineffective when a large portion only benefits from the rest of the community's work without contributing something back. Personal feelings aside, it seems that users should be encouraged to participate if only to strengthen the community.

**Most importantly, there seems to be a correlation between those who post no answers and those who post low-quality questions.** I speculate that people who don't bother to read others' questions have no reason to read the asking guidelines.

Can something be done to encourage these users to contribute? **Should** something be done? Or is the issue better left alone?

Comment: *"Can something be done to encourage these users to contribute?"* Asking non-duplicate, interesting questions is also contributing to the site.

Comment: From the (small) sample size I've seen, they don't seem to do that either.

Comment: I'd suggest close voting and possibly downvoting their questions, if those are bad. Or upvoting and potentially answering if they are good. So, the same policy as a question from anybody else.

Comment: I've posted 10 times as many answers as questions, should something be done about me then? Since every Q&A has to start with a question I'm really just taking advantage of those who post questions here when I contribute. That hyperbole aside, we need both kind of users here. We need questions and we need answers. We can't expect everyone to contribute equal amounts of each. We already have mechanisms in place to deal with users who continue to post low quality content. If you want to do something about them, use your votes.

Comment: @MichaelKolber SO already has upvotes and downvotes to rate the content, question limits and question bans for users who repeatedly post bad questions.

Comment: @ivarni There is a non-trivial difference between not having an equal amount of questions as answers versus having no answers at all. But I see your point.

Comment: @adiga This is what I was getting at, yes. There is generally a correlation between these users and low-quality questions.

Comment: @MichaelKolber sure, there are some who just post low quality questions all the time. I still don't think we should punish *all* who only post questions. If the problem are low quality questions then focus on those. Close and downvote them and that solves the problem. A person with too many bad questions (not sure the exact criteria but close and downvoting affects it) will be question banned. If a user posts, say, 10 highly voted questions in a row *I would like them to stay* not boot them out.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply said: *nothing*.

By posting a question, they are already contributing to the site. The question might be of low quality, but that is a responsibility of the author. There are plenty tools available to work with that: downvoting (yes, even if might be *sic* "unfriendly") / close votes / automated question bans.

If some of those wants to contribute by giving answers, they can do that when they want to do that. I am not fan of luring them or even "nudging" them into giving an answer. It should be done from their own.

Comment: Downvoting bad content is friendly to every occasional visitor of that question, to be fair, which are far more than the OP alone. Do use the downvote. :)